# How to replace a specific word from a dynamic list of String

Tags: java, regex, string, apache-stringutils

How to replace "**current timestamp**" from the list of string contains "**{ts '2017-01-12 16:09:20'}**", The ts value changed for each String.

Eg: //Need to replace the list of old time stamp values to current time stamp

```
private void replaceOldTimeStampToCurrentTimeStamp(){
    List<String>sampleString = new ArrayList<String>();
    sampleString.add("VALUES ('CODE','01234','DDC','DDC','',1,'01100',null,null,'Y','SD','PRODUCT','','','',2200,2603,{ts '2017-04-25 14:09:20'},'dba',{ts '2017-04-25 14:09:20'},'dba')");
    sampleString.add("VALUES ('TYPE','NW','New','New','',1,'01100',null,null,'Y','PRODUCT',null,'','',2200,2604,{ts '2017-01-12 16:09:20'},'dba',{ts '2017-01-12 16:09:20'},'dba')");
}
```

**desired output:**

VALUES('TYPE','NW','New','New','',1,'01100',null,null,'Y','PRODUCT',null,'','',2200,2604,**current timestamp**,'dba',**current timestamp**,'dba')

VALUES('CODE','01234','DDC','DDC','',1,'01100',null,null,'Y','SD','PRODUCT','','','',2200,2603,**current timestamp**,'dba',**current timestamp**,'dba')

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Check a basic regex tutorial.

Comment: SO is a questions and answers site and not please do my work

Comment: You can start checking this method: [`String replaceAll( <regex string>, <replacement string>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and check a basic Regex tutorial. There are also various questions on that method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try someting like this:

```
private void replaceOldTimeStampToCurrentTimeStamp(){
    String ts = "current timestamp" //the value you want, a string value
    List<String>sampleString = new ArrayList<String>();
    sampleString.add("VALUES ('CODE','01234','DDC','DDC','',1,'01100',null,null,'Y','SD','PRODUCT','','','',2200,2603,"+ts+",'dba',"+ts+",'dba')");
    sampleString.add("VALUES ('TYPE','NW','New','New','',1,'01100',null,null,'Y','PRODUCT',null,'','',2200,2604,"+ts+",'dba',"+ts+",'dba')");
}
```

Comment: The list not contain only two string values it contain 200. You cannot replace by put the ts value in all the 200. I need a replace method to set the value.